# Saving new entities in a One-To-Many association indexed by field through Symfony's form builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, symfony-forms

It took me way to long to get the title right, and I havent written the question yet :/

Here goes:
My menu is loaded from entities.
In order to allow the user to translate the menu into multiple languages, I created a `Menu` entity and a `LocalizedMenu` entity that is associated with `Menu` through a `ManyToOne` association.

Following [this short guide](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html), I indexed the association with the `LocalizedMenu->locale` field. This ensures that only one `LocalizedMenu` per locale exists in the database and that doctrine overwrites existing locales.

Here's What that looks like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MenuRepository")
 */
class Menu
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"menu"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * References translated menus.
     * @Groups({"localized_menus"})
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="LocalizedMenu"
     *     ,mappedBy="parentMenu"
     *     ,indexBy="locale"
     *     ,cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"locale" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $localizedMenus;

    // ...

    public function getLocalizedMenu($locale) {
        if (!isset($this->localizedMenus[$locale])) {
            return new LocalizedMenu($locale, $this);
        }
        return $this->localizedMenus[$locale];
    }

    public function addLocalizedMenu($localizedMenu): self
    {
        $this->localizedMenus[$localizedMenu->getLocale()] = $localizedMenu;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

`LocalizedMenu` is an entity that holds user translated menu fields:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LocalizedMenuRepository")
 */
class LocalizedMenu
{
    public function __construct($locale, $menu) {
        $this->locale = $locale;
        $this->parentMenu = $menu;
        $this->parentMenu->addLocalizedMenu($this);
    }

    // region FIELDS
    /**
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_menus"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_menus"})
     * @var $locale string
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type                 = "string"
     *     ,unique              = true
     * )
     */
    private $locale = "";
    /**
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_menus"})
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type                 = "string",
     *     length               = 75
     * )
     */
    private $title = "";
    /**
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_menus"})
     * @var $description string Extra description for this menu item
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type                 = "text",
     *     name                 = "description"
     * )
     */
    private $description = "";
    /**
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_menus"})
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type                 = "datetime",
     *     name                 = "creation_date"
     * )
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $creationDate;
    /**
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_menus"})
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type                 = "datetime",
     *     name                 = "edit_date"
     * )
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $editDate;

    /**
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_menus"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message = "Een menu item is een pagina die inhoud nodig heeft, vergeet dit niet"
     * )
     */
    private $content = "";

    /**
     * @var $parentMenu Menu Parent menu for this localized menu
     *
     * @Groups({"localized_menu", "localized_parent_menu"})
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="Menu",
     *     inversedBy="localizedMenus"
     * )
     */
    private $parentMenu;
}
```

To bring this all to the user for editing, I created a `MenyType` form:

```
    $builder
        ->add('localizedMenus', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => LocalizedMenuType::class,
            "entry_options" => [
                "choice_locale" => $options["choice_locale"]
            ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'required' => false
        ))
```

And a `LocalizedMenuType` form:

```
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
            'label'             => 'Titel',
            'trim'              => true
        ))
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array(
            'label'             => 'Omschrijving',
            'trim'              => true
        ))
        ->add('content', TextareaType::class, array(
            'label'             => 'Inhoud',
            'trim'              => true,
            'attr'              => array('class' => 'tinymce'),
            'data'              => "&nbsp;"
        ))
        ->add('locale', LocaleType::class, array(
            "choice_translation_locale" => $options["choice_locale"]
        ))
    ;
```

I "think" this logic is correct, but after using javascript to create new `LocalizedMenu` forms, I get this error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Entity\LocalizedMenu::__construct(),
>   0 passed in
>   /Users/robbievercammen/Projects/web/base/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php
>   on line 136 and exactly 2 expected

How can I get my form to work gracefully with my logic?

**EDIT - THE REAL ISSUE**

The error message isn't the real error here. As I said before, if I remove the constructor parameters, it does save the records to the database. i.e. Letting doctrine use the association to associate new `LocalizedMenu` records to the `Menu` record. This is what it looks like in the database:

`Menu`

```
|id| //...
| 7| //...
```

`LocalizedMenu`

```
| id | locale | title   | description | creation_date       | edit_date           
| content | parent_menu_id |
----
|  4 | nl     | Contact | Contact     | 2019-02-21 14:02:47 | 2019-02-21 14:02:47 |
 Contact |           NULL |
```

the problem is `LocalizedMenu -> parent_menu_id` is NULL.
For some reason, my setup does not generate id's for the parent menu.
The next time the menu is fetched from the database, `$menu->getLocalizedMenus()` returns an empty array because they are not associated properly.

Following the [guide](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html) I mentioned, this does seem like the only way I can tell doctrine to index by `$localizedMenu -> locale`

Comment: Hi. What do you want to know? The reason why you have an error or How to fix this error?

Comment: I know why I have an error, but I don't know how I can fix it. Specifically how to integrate the `index-by` logic into the form

Comment: Symfony form doesn't "like" constructor with arguments. This error does not related to `index-by`option at all. Look at this articles: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/use_empty_data.html, https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html

Comment: @PavelStepanets, Hi, yes I know it is not related :/ At this point, the form in question generates completely new entities. This means `Menu` and `LocalizedMenu` don't have an ID yet (null or -1). I can remove the constructor paramters and all entities will be created as expected, but new `LocalizedMenu` instances will have their `parentId`s set to NULL because the parent's ID doesn't exist yet untill I call `$em->persist`. `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` is responsible for this behavior. I guess I'll have to remove persist and persist each `LocalizedMenu` manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LocalizedMenu` constructor requires two arguments - `$locale` and `$menu`. When Symfony instantiates the new `LocalizedMenu` instance for your newly submitted data, it does a straight `new LocalizedMenu()` to populate its data.

If you need to customize how an object is created for new/dynamic content in a form (for instance when you have constructor arguments), you must set the `empty_data` option on your `LocalizedMenuType` class.

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/use_empty_data.html for more information.

One of your `LocalizedMenu` constructor arguments is a menu instance. This menu instance will need to be passed in to your `LocalizedMenuType` as a required option.

```
class LocalizedMenuType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('menu');
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('menu', Menu::class);
        $resolver->setDefault('empty_data', function (Options $options) {
            return new LocalizedMenu($options['choice_locale'], $options['menu']);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see the source of the FormType class to understand how an instance of your `data_class` is instantiated by default. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L130-L143

Comment: Hi Malcolm, thanks for your answer. This is actually a great way to fix the issue. My confusion was caused due to the assumption symfony would handle associating the localized menu with it's parent. I decided to use `$localizedMenu->setParent($menu)` to manually link the parent to each localized menu.
Your asnwer would solve it too, so I'll accept it :)